# Calendar Views issue

Tags: views, datetime

I'm using Calendar module and I have trouble with calendars implemented by this module. I want to create a Drupal 7 Calendar View which uses two fields (date type) from the same Content Type.

The problem is the View displays duplicated values in Calendar when I use 2 different fields. When I use a single field the View is ok.

Had anybody the same issue?

Comment: Have you tried adding distinct in query settings?

Comment: Yes, I tried but no results

Comment: I have had issues with distinct at times. Sometimes it does not actually add it to the query. Does it show up in your select statement? Also, how attached are you to the Calendar module? If you continue to have issues you may want to try [FullCalendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar). It cleared up a lot of issues that we had with the Calendar module.

Comment: Finally I managed to fix this issue using two Date fields from two different Content types.